# spinnaker/halyard : Unable to deploy apply spinnaker on GKE

Tags: kubernetes, spinnaker, google-kubernetes-engine

I am following step written it the official tutorial [Try out Halyard on GKE](https://www.spinnaker.io/setup/quickstart/halyard-gke/)

I am trying the deployment step but the `hal deploy apply` is not working.

I ran this command and it returned no error like below.

```
hal config deploy edit     --account-name my-k8s-account     --type distributed

+ Get current deployment
  Success
+ Get the deployment environment
  Success
- No changes supplied.
```

After this command, I ran this command `hal deploy apply`.
But the `Prep deployment` fails and return this error.

```
! ERROR Unable to communicate with your Kubernetes cluster: Failure
  executing: GET at: https://35.200.120.197/api/v1/namespaces. Message: 
  Forbidden!
  User gke_helm-gke-test_asia-northeast1-b_helm-test doesn't have permission.
  namespaces is forbidden: User "client" cannot list namespaces at the cluster
  scope: Unknown user "client"..
```

How can I solve this problem?

My hal version is

```
$ hav -v
0.48.1-20180413145934
```

Comment: Did you add the Kubernetes provider before (following this guide i note that you don't mention it)? The error is regarding to permissions at cluster scope. Can you check the cluster scopes?

Answer (score 0):

A user in our chat room said this thread helped him work through a similar RBAC auth issue: https://github.com/spinnaker/spinnaker/issues/2421